# Spring WebClient - Stop retrying if an exception is thrown in the doOnError

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I have the following code to make a request that is going to be retried a max number of times. This request needs an authorization header and I'm caching this information to prevent this method to call the method to retrieve this information every time.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. When calling myMethod I first retrieve the login information for the service I'm calling, in most cases that will come from the cache when calling the getAuthorizationHeaderValue method.
2. In the web client, if the response to send this request returns a 4xx response I need to login again to the service I'm calling, before retrying the request. For that, I'm calling the tryToLoginAgain method to set the value for the header again.
3. After doing that the retry of the request should work now that the header has been set.
4. If by any chance the call to login again fails I need to stop retrying as there no use on retrying the request.

```
public <T> T myMethod(...) {
    ...

    try {
        AtomicReference<String> headerValue = new AtomicReference<>(loginService.getAuthorizationHeaderValue());

        Mono<T> monoResult = webclient.get()
                .uri(uri)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, headerValue.get())
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> throwHttpClientLoginException())
                .bodyToMono(type)
                .doOnError(HttpClientLoginException.class, e -> tryToLoginAgain(headerValue))
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(MAX_NUMBER_RETRIES, Duration.ofSeconds(5)));

        result = monoResult.block();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new HttpClientException("There was an error while sending the request");
    }
    return result;
}

...

private Mono<Throwable> throwHttpClientLoginException() {
    return Mono.error(new HttpClientLoginException("Existing Authorization failed"));
}

private void tryToLoginAgain(AtomicReference<String> headerValue) {
    loginService.removeAccessTokenFromCache();
    
    headerValue.set(loginService.getAuthorizationHeaderValue());
}
```

I have some unit tests and the happy path works fine (unauthorized the first time, try to login again and send the request again) but the scenario where the login doesn't work at all is not working.

I thought that if the tryToLoginAgain method throws an Exception that would be caught by the catch I have in myMethod but it never reaches there, it just retries the request again. Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end I found a way of doing what I wanted and now the code looks like this:

```
public <T> T myMethod() {
    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBearerAuth(getAuthorizationHeaderValue());

        final RetryBackoffSpec retrySpec = Retry.backoff(MAX_NUMBER_RETRIES, Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .doBeforeRetry(retrySignal -> {
                //When retrying, if this was a login error, try to login again
                if (retrySignal.failure() instanceof HttpClientLoginException) {
                    tryToLoginAgain(headers);
                }
            });

        Mono<T> monoResult = Mono.defer(() ->
                getRequestFromMethod(httpMethod, uri, body, headers)
                    .retrieve()
                    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> throwHttpClientLoginException())
                    .bodyToMono(type)
            )
            .retryWhen(retrySpec);

        result = monoResult.block();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String requestUri = uri != null ?
            uri.toString() :
            endpoint;

        log.error("There was an error while sending the request [{}] [{}]", httpMethod.name(), requestUri);

        throw new HttpClientException("There was an error while sending the request [" + httpMethod.name() +
            "] [" + requestUri + "]");
    }

    return result;
}

private void tryToLoginAgain(HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
    //If there was an 4xx error, let's evict the cache to remove the existing access_token (if it exists)
    loginService.removeAccessTokenFromCache();
    //And let's try to login again
    httpHeaders.setBearerAuth(getAuthorizationHeaderValue());
}

private Mono<Throwable> throwHttpClientLoginException() {
    return Mono.error(new HttpClientLoginException("Existing Authorization failed"));
}

private WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec getRequestFromMethod(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri, Object body, HttpHeaders headers) {
    switch (httpMethod) {
        case GET:
            return webClient.get()
                .uri(uri)
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        case POST:
            return body == null ?
                webClient.post()
                    .uri(uri)
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) :
                webClient.post()
                    .uri(uri)
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .bodyValue(body);
        case PUT:
            return body == null ?
                webClient.put()
                    .uri(uri)
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) :
                webClient.put()
                    .uri(uri)
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .bodyValue(body);
        case DELETE:
            return webClient.delete()
                .uri(uri)
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        default:
            log.error("Method [{}] is not supported", httpMethod.name());
            throw new HttpClientException("Method [" + httpMethod.name() + "] is not supported");
    }
}

private String getAuthorizationHeaderValue() {
    return loginService.retrieveAccessToken();
}
```

By using `Mono.defer()` I can retry on that Mono and make sure I change the headers I'll use with the WebClient. The retry spec will check if the exception was of the `HttpClientLoginException` type, thrown when the request gets a 4xx status code and in that case it will try to login again and set the header for the next retry. If the status code was different it will retry again using the same authorization.

Also, if there's an error when we try to login again, that will be caught by the catch and it won't retry anymore.